# Postgres INSERT INTO with SELECT

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to write some SQL to insert records into a PG table.

This is the logic:

- For every record in the costprojects table that has coststatus_id=1
- insert a new record into costestimates table

  - costcat_id=30, amount=0, costproject_id=costproject.id(from the costprojects record) , maintenance=‘FALSE’, position=22

This is the SQL code I tried:

```
INSERT INTO costestimates (costcat_id, amount, costproject_id, maintenance, position) VALUES (30, 0, costproject.id, false, 22)
(SELECT id FROM costprojects WHERE coststatus_id=1)
```

I get ERROR: syntax error at or near "("

Comment: `INSERT INTO costestimates (costcat_id, amount, costproject_id, maintenance, position) SELECT 30, 0, id, false, 22 FROM costprojects WHERE coststatus_id=1;`

Comment: You dont need the values(), you can just do `insert into aa(...) SELECT 1,2,3 , x.y from x where x.z = 4;`

Comment: ildar-musin - thanks - if you answer, I will accept

Comment: @Reddirt, done : )

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO costestimates (costcat_id, amount, costproject_id, maintenance, position)
SELECT 30, 0, id, false, 22 FROM costprojects WHERE coststatus_id=1;
```

See [postgres INSERT syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html)

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is a bit off; what you want is to actually compose the VALUES list using your SELECT statement.

Try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO
  costestimates (costcat_id, amount, costproject_id, maintenance, position)
  (SELECT 30, 0, id, false, 22 FROM costprojects WHERE coststatus_id=1)
```

Comment: The parentheses around the `select` are totally useless.

Comment: yes, but also harmless, and adding them helps communicate the parallelism between `INSERT INTO table () VALUES ()` and `INSERT INTO table () (SELECT )`

Answer (score 0):

```
Insert Into Table1
Select id,name,age from Table2;
```

`Table1` is our newly created table where we are dumping records from `Table2` of specific columns only. We don't need to mention `Table1` columns name if we are taking same columns in `Select` query.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.